# Preview Composable in Another Language

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

This code make preview composable dark theme true or not.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun AppPreview() {
    AppBookTheme(darkTheme = false) {
        TheBookApp()
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun AppDarkThemePreview() {
    AppBookTheme(darkTheme = true, 
    ) {
        TheBookApp()
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change the default preview composable language too ?

*...
It's not necessary to explain to me how to change the language from the virtual phone or IDE settings ;)*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `locale` argument to specify the language.

```kotlin
@Preview(locale = "en")
@Composable
fun PreviewComponent() {
  ...
}
```

Checkout [LocalQualifier](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#LocaleQualifier)